# How to override OrderDiscountForViewing class prestashop 1.7.8.3

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have a problem with override class **src\Core\Domain\Order\QueryResult\OrderDiscountForViewing.php**

I need to override this class and add custom property coupon **code**.
How to do this?

```
class OrderDiscountForViewing
    {
       
        private $code;
    
        public function __construct(
            int $orderCartRuleId,
            string $name,
            DecimalNumber $amountRaw,
            string $amountFormatted,
            string $code = null
        ) {
            $this->orderCartRuleId = $orderCartRuleId;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->amountFormatted = $amountFormatted;
            $this->amountRaw = $amountRaw;
            $this->code = $code;
        }
    
        public function getCode(): string
        {
            return $this->code;
        }
    }
```